# Java Iterator For-Each

Tags: java

```
public class English {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        int a = 0;
        while (a < 5) {
            arrayList.add(new EnglishTranslator("English"));
            ++a;
        }
        for (Object item: arrayList) {
            System.out.println(item.translate);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Translator {
        public abstract String getLanguage();

        public String translate() {
            return "Я переводчик с " + getLanguage();
        }
    }

    public static class EnglishTranslator extends Translator {
        public static String language;

        public EnglishTranslator(String language) {
            this.language = language;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return this.language;
        }

        public String translate() {
            return "Я " + getLanguage() + " переводчик";
        }
    }
}
```

> //Почему я не могу написать в for-each: item.translate? я же заполнил
>   массив объектами одинаковыми, но не могу вызвать у них метод.
>   Компилятор просто-напросто не видит их.

Comment: во-первых `translate` у вас метод, а не поле... значит надо `translate()`.... во-вторых использовать дженерик  `ArrayList<EnglishTranslator> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`  и соответственно в цикле `for (EnglishTranslator item: arrayList) {` ........ либо использовать `for`....и работу с методами листа- например `for(int i = 0; i <arrayList.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i).translate());
        }`

Comment: Спасибо. А почему мой вариант не катит?

Comment: Кстати говоря ArrayList не массив.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что у класса `Object` нет метода `translate()`

Когда вы пишете, `for (Object item : arrayList)`, вы на каждой итерации цикла "объявляете" переменную `item` типа `Object`. Поэтому компилятор "не знает", объект какого типа на самом деле содержится в переменной, и не дает вызывать методы, которых нет у `Object`. Указать там `Translator` не получится, поскольку список работает с `Object`.

Вам нужно использовать generics, специализировав коллекцию `arrayList`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Translator> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    int a = 0;
    while (a < 5) {
        arrayList.add(new EnglishTranslator("English"));
        ++a;
    }
    for (Translator item: arrayList) {
        System.out.println(item.translate());
    }
}
```

Так вы указываете, что в коллекции будут содержаться объекты класса `Translator` (или его подтипов). Компилятор это учтет, и не даст, например, вызывать `.add` для объектов других классов, а тип возвращаемого значения у `get` будет сразу `Translator`.

Comment: Спасибо большое . Все стало понятно